# Jpa is not fetching 1 to N relationship

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have 3 entity classes:

```
@Table(name = "offer")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="type")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Offer extends Audited {
    ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="offer", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<CompanyOffer> deals;

}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("moving")
public class MovingOffer extends Offer {...}

@Table(name = "company_offer")
public class CompanyOffer extends Audited {
    ...

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(
        name = "offer_id",
        foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_companyoffer_offer")
    )
    private Offer offer;

}
```

The tables are created all like expected, but when I want to get a `MovingOffer`, then there are no `deals`. The deals property is always set to `null`, although the values are stored in the database correctly.

In the logs of hibernate I could find the following line:

```
No collections were found in result set for role: com.company.entity.Offer.deals
```

Any hints where the problem could be?

Edit:
For fetching the data I use a JpaRepository. Using the Method `findFullById`

```
public interface MovingOfferRepository extends JpaRepository<MovingOffer, UUID> {

    @Query("SELECT mo FROM MovingOffer mo LEFT JOIN FETCH mo.deals WHERE mo.id = ?1")
    MovingOffer findFullById(UUID movingOfferId);

}
```

Here are the table definitions for all 3  directly from postgres:

```
                                        Table "public.offer"
  Column      |            Type             | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description
 type             | character varying(31)       | not null  | extended |              |
 id               | uuid                        | not null  | plain    |              |
 createdat        | timestamp without time zone | not null  | plain    |              |
 lastmodifiedat   | timestamp without time zone | not null  | plain    |              |
 deliverydate     | bytea                       |           | extended |              |
 externalorderid  | character varying(255)      |           | extended |              |
 status           | character varying(255)      | not null  | extended |              |
 customer_id      | uuid                        |           | plain    |              |
Indexes:
    "offer_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_offer_customer" FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customer(id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "company_offer" CONSTRAINT "fk_companyoffer_offer" FOREIGN KEY (offer_id) REFERENCES offer(id)
    TABLE "movingoffer" CONSTRAINT "fkg74slpkg2tob4b3ydqilcfdrn" FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES offer(id)


                      Table "public.movingoffer"
  Column      |  Type   | Modifiers | Storage | Stats target | Description
------------------+---------+-----------+---------+--------------+-------------
 boxcount         | integer |           | plain   |              |
 id               | uuid    | not null  | plain   |              |
 startaddress_id  | uuid    | not null  | plain   |              |
 targetaddress_id | uuid    | not null  | plain   |              |
Indexes:
    "movingoffer_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_address_from" FOREIGN KEY (startaddress_id) REFERENCES address(id)
    "fk_address_to" FOREIGN KEY (targetaddress_id) REFERENCES address(id)
    "fkg74slpkg2tob4b3ydqilcfdrn" FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES offer(id)



                                Table "public.company_offer"
  Column       |            Type             | Modifiers | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
-------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+--------------+-------------


id                | uuid                        | not null  | plain    |              | 
 createdat         | timestamp without time zone | not null  | plain    |              | 
 lastmodifiedat    | timestamp without time zone | not null  | plain    |              | 
 estimatedduration | double precision            |           | plain    |              | 
 message           | text                        |           | extended |              | 
 totalprice        | numeric(19,2)               |           | main     |              | 
 company_id        | uuid                        | not null  | plain    |              | 
 offer_id          | uuid                        | not null  | plain    |              | 
Indexes:
    "company_offer_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_companyoffer_company" FOREIGN KEY (company_id) REFERENCES company(id)
    "fk_companyoffer_offer" FOREIGN KEY (offer_id) REFERENCES offer(id)
```

Comment: How are you feching the entities? Post some code.

Comment: added my repository, so you can see the query

Comment: do you really need the foreign key in the `@JoinColumn`? how are your tables defined?

Comment: Why would you need that query? The relationship is already `EAGER` so it is fetched anyway. Have you tried the default `findOne`?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I just got the JoinColumn, so I can define a custom foreign key.

Comment: I know I just put that EAGER there for testing purposes. It should be lazy

Comment: can you show, how your columns are defined?

Comment: do columns, which identify the relationship are posted above, do you need some more. Or do I missunderstood you?

Comment: sorry, i made bad wording. i mean that you show us the table definition

Comment: I added the 3 table definitions

Comment: Is `Offer` declared as an `@Entity` or a `@MappedSuperclass`?

Comment: the offer is an entity object. If I change it to a MappedSuperclass I get an AnnotationException: `@OneToOne or @ManyToOne on at.company.entity.CompanyOffer.offer references an unknown entity: at.company.entity.Offer`